# AutoLayout and Constraints iOS 6

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, layout, storyboard

I am having the worst time with autolayout and constraints in my app. I have a specific view in a storyboard that is especially bad. The subview will be stretched to off screen and the buttons and such in that subview will either stretch with it, or not at all.

Normally if things get out of wack I just have to move it around a little and it will go back to how it should be, however, when I do that in this specific view it just makes things worse! I am not sure what to provide to help those who help me, so please ask if you need more info. Is there a way to fix this? I am really getting frustrated with this whole autolayout constraint issue. It occures everytime I need to make an adjustment to the view!

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Are you setting it up in IB? If so, please provide a screenshot with the constraints. If you set them up in code, please provide the code.

Comment: Could you upload a screenshot so we can visualise a little bit your scenario ?

Comment: Thanks for the screenshot. Just another suggestion, could you rewrite your question, it's quite difficult to grasp what your intention is and what you have tried and failed with already.

Comment: So I have tried a few more things. I have disabled and then reenabled auto layout and then I also completely rebuilt the view. Nothing fixed it.